# How do I get shoes executable into my path?

Tags: ruby, macos, shoes

I'm getting started with shoes and the nks docs tell me two write a script and then launch it like this:

```
> shoes myapp.rb
```

the shoes executable is in the Shoes.app I installed. Thus, shoes is not in my path so I can't do this.

Tried symlinking shoes into /usr/local/bin but I get this error when I try to start it.

```
> shoes myapp.rb
FSPathMakeRef(/usr/local/bin/../../../Shoes.app) failed with error -43.
```

any ideas?

Geoff

PS. Additional information: OSX Leopard. Shoes version, Raisins. Installed from dmg. The link was made from and absolute path ->

```
> sudo ln -s /Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes shoes
```

Comment: Can you give us some more details - like what operating system, what version of shoes, how you installed shoes, where you installed shoes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give an absolute path when making the symlink

and you need to give the path inside the app bundle, such as `Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/Shoes` maybe

Edit:

you could always add the following line to your .profile (assuming bash)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

although it's not a very nice solution

Edit:

```
alias shoes=/Applications/Shoes.app/Contents/MacOS/shoes
```

may be a cleaner solution

Comment: I suppose the ideal way to do it would be to write a small script to call /Applications/... and place it in your existing path